# Mean Variance Optimization vs Risk Scaling

Tags: portfolio-optimization, risk-management, mean-variance

What would be the difference between the following. Both techniques will result is an ex-ante risk of $\sigma$. However, that would be achieved via two different values of h. I want to understand which might be superior or better.

1. **Doing a mean variance optimization** :

$h = \frac{V^{-1} \alpha}{2 \lambda} $  choosing

$\lambda = \sqrt{\frac{\alpha^T V ^{-1} \alpha}{4 \sigma^2}}$

which is just risk targeting to $\sigma$.

2. **Scaling your weights (signal) to risk target.**

$h = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\alpha^T V \alpha}} \alpha$

Notations:

$h$ : Final weights

$V$ : Covariance matrix

$\alpha$: Signal ( assume it to be normal in the cross section)

If we calculate the ex-ante risk we will get $\sigma$ from both
ex-Ante risk: $h^TVh$

Comment: Both techniques target an ex-ante volatility of $\sigma$. $\lambda$ is the Lagrangian multiplier and for a specific solution, one would have to specify the value of $\lambda$

Comment: Ok, I see. Sort of. I'll think about it.